# Formula for output value given a restricted range of input - Slider UI

Tags: algorithm, math, slider, formula, uislider

Given these parameters:

```
minX = 10.0
maxX = 200.0
minY = 300
maxY = 700
```

The user can move x between minX and maxX. Find y so that it is the same proportionally between minY and maxY as x is between minX and maxX. So if x = 10, y = 300. If x = 200, y = 700.

Although x is a float, y must be an int.

What would this formula look like?

I've tried the below, but it works in an inverse fashion.

```
y = minY + (double)(maxX - x) / maxX * (maxY - minY)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
((x - minX) / (double)(maxX - minX)) * (maxY - minY) + minY
```

`((x - minX) / (double)(maxX - minX))` computes the "percentage" of `x` in `x`'s range. Then you simply multiply by the magnitude (`(maxY - minY)`) of the y range and add the lower bound to get `y`